# What to do with an abandoned puppy

Tags: dogs

A mother gave birth to 5 puppies near my apartment, which is in an isolated area, a short while ago. I only noticed them 4 nights ago and started to feed her 2 chicken drumsticks everyday which is no where near enough but it was all I could do. She gave birth to one brown puppy, 3 which are a mixture of brown and white and one completely black which is the odd one out. I didn't notice anything odd yesterday but today I noticed that she moved her all puppies to a new new location, only a few feet away from the old one, except her black puppy which was left all alone. I picked it up and put it with its brothers and sisters and that point is started drizzling. I came back after 2 hours and found that the mother had moved all her puppies again to a warmer location except for the black one. It was left out in the cold under the rain and it screeching while it's mother was only 5 steps away and seemed to pay it no mind. Clearly she has decided to abandon this one. I picked her up, brought her home and warmed her up with a blanket but I don't know what I should do. It does not seem to have any congenital abnormalities. I don't know if it is sick or if the mother just can't take care of all five so she had to abandon  one. There is no vet out here where I live and definitely no store that sells puppy milk formula. What do I do with it and what do I feed it?

Comment: http://www.peteducation.com/article.cfm?c=2+2099&aid=863

Comment: Can I ask what country you are in? That makes a huge difference to the options available to you

Answer (score 3):

Call the nearest dog rescue center and ask them for advice.  They deal with this kind of case all of the time.

Comment: Depends what country this person is in. Not every place is fortunate enough to have these things.